# Java-WS Eclipse ignoring interface-customization annotations

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, wsdl

I have been trying to build a Jave Web Service using Eclipse (Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers, Kepler Service Release 1). I wrote the code, and used Eclipse to generate a web service for it (which would also create the WSDL file for it). I notice that resultant web service seems to ignore all interface annotations (@WebMethod, @WebResult...etc.).  Using wsgen, all the annotations seem to be respected.

Is this by design or am I doing something wrong here?

Below is the source code of the service, with the WSDL generated by Eclipse following:

```
package org.itemKeyGenerator;

import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.NoSuchElementException;

import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebResult;
import javax.jws.WebService;

import org.itemKeyGenerator.beans.DocumentKey;
import org.itemKeyGenerator.beans.ElementKey;
import org.itemKeyGenerator.beans.GroupKey;

@WebService (serviceName = "itemKeyGeneratorService", portName = "itemKeyGenerator")
public class ItemKeyGeneratorService {

    private static DatabaseAdapter adapter = new DatabaseAdapter();

    public ItemKeyGeneratorService() {}

    @WebMethod(operationName = "generate_document_key")
    @WebResult(name = "key")
    public DocumentKey generateDocumentKey() throws SQLException, NoSuchElementException {
        return adapter.generateAndGetDocumentKey();
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "generate_group_key")
    public @WebResult(name = "key")GroupKey generateGroupKey(
            DocumentKey k) throws SQLException, NoSuchElementException {
        return adapter.generateAndGetInvoiceElementGroupKey(k);
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName = "generate_element_key")
    public @WebResult(name = "key")ElementKey generateElementKey(
            GroupKey k) throws SQLException, NoSuchElementException {
        return adapter.generateAndGetInvoiceElementDetailKey(k);
    }

}
```

Eclipse generated WSDL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions targetNamespace="http://itemKeyGenerator.org" xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap" xmlns:impl="http://itemKeyGenerator.org" xmlns:intf="http://itemKeyGenerator.org" xmlns:tns1="http://beans.itemKeyGenerator.org" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:wsdlsoap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<!--WSDL created by Apache Axis version: 1.4
Built on Apr 22, 2006 (06:55:48 PDT)-->
 <wsdl:types>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://itemKeyGenerator.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <import namespace="http://beans.itemKeyGenerator.org"/>
   <element name="generateDocumentKey">
    <complexType/>
   </element>
   <element name="generateDocumentKeyResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="generateDocumentKeyReturn" type="tns1:DocumentKey"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKey">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="k" type="tns1:DocumentKey"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyReturn" type="tns1:InvoiceElementGroupKey"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKey">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="k" type="tns1:InvoiceElementGroupKey"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
   <element name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyResponse">
    <complexType>
     <sequence>
      <element name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyReturn" type="tns1:InvoiceElementDetailKey"/>
     </sequence>
    </complexType>
   </element>
  </schema>
  <schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://beans.itemKeyGenerator.org" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
   <complexType name="DocumentKey">
    <sequence>
     <element name="documentKey" type="xsd:long"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="InvoiceElementGroupKey">
    <sequence>
     <element name="documentKey" nillable="true" type="tns1:DocumentKey"/>
     <element name="invoiceElementGroupKey" type="xsd:long"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
   <complexType name="InvoiceElementDetailKey">
    <sequence>
     <element name="invoiceElementDetailKey" type="xsd:long"/>
     <element name="invoiceElementGroupKey" nillable="true" type="tns1:InvoiceElementGroupKey"/>
    </sequence>
   </complexType>
  </schema>
 </wsdl:types>

   <wsdl:message name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:generateInvoiceElementDetailKey" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="generateDocumentKeyResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:generateDocumentKeyResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:generateInvoiceElementGroupKey" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="generateDocumentKeyRequest">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:generateDocumentKey" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:message name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyResponse">

      <wsdl:part element="impl:generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyResponse" name="parameters">

      </wsdl:part>

   </wsdl:message>

   <wsdl:portType name="ItemKeyGeneratorService">

      <wsdl:operation name="generateDocumentKey">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:generateDocumentKeyRequest" name="generateDocumentKeyRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:generateDocumentKeyResponse" name="generateDocumentKeyResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKey">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyRequest" name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyResponse" name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKey">

         <wsdl:input message="impl:generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyRequest" name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyRequest">

       </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output message="impl:generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyResponse" name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyResponse">

       </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:portType>

   <wsdl:binding name="ItemKeyGeneratorServiceSoapBinding" type="impl:ItemKeyGeneratorService">

      <wsdlsoap:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>

      <wsdl:operation name="generateDocumentKey">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="generateDocumentKeyRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="generateDocumentKeyResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKey">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="generateInvoiceElementGroupKeyResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

      <wsdl:operation name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKey">

         <wsdlsoap:operation soapAction=""/>

         <wsdl:input name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyRequest">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:input>

         <wsdl:output name="generateInvoiceElementDetailKeyResponse">

            <wsdlsoap:body use="literal"/>

         </wsdl:output>

      </wsdl:operation>

   </wsdl:binding>

   <wsdl:service name="ItemKeyGeneratorServiceService">

      <wsdl:port binding="impl:ItemKeyGeneratorServiceSoapBinding" name="ItemKeyGeneratorService">

         <wsdlsoap:address location="http://localhost:8080/KeyGeneratorService/services/ItemKeyGeneratorService"/>

      </wsdl:port>

   </wsdl:service>

</wsdl:definitions>
```

I have spent the past week playing with it, searching for answers, and trying to figure it out. I would appreciate any help on this matter.

Many thanks!

- Lawrence

Comment: I think the problem could be a classpath issue.  How are you managing your classpath?  What jar are you expecting to be on your classpath to support those annotations?  How are you building/compiling your project?  Ant?  Maven?  Scripts?  manually?  Are you running the web app entirely inside eclipse?  or on a local installation of jetty?  tomcat?  JBoss?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am managing it using Eclipe (Right click on project -> Properties -> Java Build Path).

I am not expected any Jar files except the ones that Eclipse decided to include.

I am letting Eclipse handle the building of the project, and also letting it handle the whole starting and shutdown of Glassfish.

Comment: I just want to say I have since tried to run the project directly (Right click project -> Run -> Run on Server) without the WSDL file generated by creating a new web service base on the project, and all the annotations seem to be respected (i.e. operation names, parameter names...etc.)

Comment: are you saying that the project in eclipse was not originally a "dynamic web project"?  and you re-configured it so eclipse recognizes it as a web project now?  is your problem solved now?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply (Power and internet outage due to local storm).

Yes, the problem seems to be resolved now.

The project was originally a dynamic web project. The problem seems to be resolved when I do not use Eclipse's "New Web Service" wizard to generate the WSDL file; instead, use wsgen.

Thanks again, msknapp!